# Are there any disadvantages in setting a lower java compliance level than the available java sdk?

Tags: javac

When updating a large java project from one LTS version (java 1.x) to the next (java 17), one may set the java compliance level of the compiler of the new javac compiler to match older versions of the standard, so that the compiled bytecode can be run with older java runtime environments that may be installed on the user devices. This advantage is plausible to me, but is there any downsides to doing this?

I have updated my java version in my project, but are unsure of the consequences of setting a lower compliance level for the compiler.